# Password to open file but no password to run file

Tags: python, linux, command-line, raspberry-pi

I am planning on selling a device which uses a raspberry pi. I have code stored on my raspberry pi that I would not like people to access. I was wondering if it was possible to run a file from the command line by using sudo python file_name, but if I was trying to view the file I would have to enter some sort of password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "good" solution to your problem ([the DRM problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)). Anything you can do to protect your source has to be undone in order to run the code, and there is nothing stopping anyone from simply watching it at that point. So even if you were to encrypt your code, it has to be decrypted in order to run, and it will just be viewed then instead.

The best you can really do is package your code into a natively compiled executable using [Cython](http://cython.org/) and hope nobody cares enough to disassemble it.

Cython is recommended over py2exe, as py2exe can be easily perused by those that know how.